# Troubles upgrading from PHP 7.0 to PHP 7.2 on Windows 7

Tags: php, windows, upgrade

I have upgraded from PHP 7.0, which worked perfectly on both my development Windows 7 machines, to PHP 7.2. On one machine Apache server 2.4.17 won't even start. On the other one Apache starts normally, but when I run my site I can't seem to get the openSSL to work. I get the error that `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is unknown function. I repeat, everything works fine on 7.0. I use the same php.ini file for both versions. 
Also, the only difference between the machines is that the one on which Apache won't start has Visual Studio 2017 installed, while the other one does not.

I also need to mention that upgrade to 7.1 doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Goran

Comment: It is never a good idea to blindly reuse the same `php.ini` on 2 different versions of PHP. Stuff in there changes!

Comment: I actually tried from the scratch and editing the php.ini - development to add the same features that I needed but still no use.

Answer (score -1):

Did you enable OpenSSL in php.ini?

**Change:**

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**To:**

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: If I didn't do that it wouldn't have worked on 7.0 either